# Enable vector layer using an expression via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, vector

How do I go about enabling a vector layer using an expression via PyQGIS?

See screenshot below for location of field, and a sample expression:

[image]

I'm new to using PyQGIS and not sure if I should be using [QgsSymbolRenderContext](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSymbolRenderContext.html#qgis.core.QgsSymbolRenderContext.expressionContextScope), but I can't figure out how to get it working.

Here's what I've tried without success:

```
qrc = QgsRenderContext()
u = QgsUnitTypes.RenderUnit()
expression = QgsExpressionContextScope("@atlas_pagename = 'Column_2'")
symbolScope = QgsSymbolRenderContext(qrc,u)
symbolScope.setExpressionContextScope(expression)
```